# Can the traefik dashboard be setup to listen over HTTPS?

Tags: traefik

I can access my dashboard at http://localhost:8080/ which is great.  However, what if I wanted to access it at https://localhost:8080/ (or some other port, like perhaps 8443).  How would I do this?

I've tried:

```
  [entryPoints.traefik]
  address = ":8080"
    [entryPoints.traefik.tls]
      [[entryPoints.traefik.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "C:/Certs/server.crt"
      keyFile = "C:/Certs/server.key"
```

However, this doesn't seem to change anything.  I can still access over http, and trying https gives me the error "This site can’t provide a secure connection".

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, so perhaps it's not possible?

Comment: Could you update your description to add your complete configuration and logs from the start of Traefik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that your configuration is correct:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

 [entryPoints.foo]
   address=":8080"
  [entryPoints.foo.tls]
      [[entryPoints.foo.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "C:/Certs/server.crt"
      keyFile = "C:/Certs/server.key"

[api]
entrypoint="foo"
```

https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/api/#authentication

Your certificate must match with your domain.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like that config is working.  Not sure what was wrong with my first attempt.